# Laravel построение архитектуры

Tags: laravel

Задача стоит следующая:
В view надо отобразить предыдущую новость. Решение написать функцию в модели

```
public function getPrevious()
{
    $postID = self::where('id', '<', $this->id)->max('id'); //ID
    return self::find($postID);
}
```

с выборкой из базы. Проблема при отображении во вьюшке, надо там писать

```
{{$post->getPrevious()->title}}
{{$post->getPrevious()->slug}}
{{$post->getPrevious()->img}}
```

Получается 3 sql запроса. Как найти красивое решение не прибегая к объявления переменной во вьюшке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А как вы представляете то, что нужно сохранить значение и не использовать переменную? Можно сделать вот так:

```
public function getPrevious()
{
        if (!isset($this->previous)) {
            $this->previous = self::where('id', '<', $this->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first(); // firstOrFail так же можно, зависит от вашей логики.
        }
        return $this->previous;
}
```

Comment: Да кстати спасибо, что то сам не додумался. Я имел ввиду не создавая переменную в самом шаблоне. 
#php
$result = $post->getPrevious();
#endphp

{{$result->title}}
{{$result->img}}